# Java to find nearest value in array

Tags: random, nearest-neighbor

i'm developing an implementation of ant colony algorithm, and stuck at find nearest value process. here is the problem.

i have an array contains cummulative probabilities, let say: cummulativeProb:{0.0, 0.34782608695652173, 0.8695652173913044, 1.0}

and there is a random number: randomNumber: 0,3323792320

i want application choose nearest value from randomNumber, but NOT bigger than randomNumber, that means application will choose 0.34782608695652173

can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte%5b%5d,%20byte%29) this will give you the element that equals what you are looking for, or -ve the index that is lower than what you are looking for.